# get value in one column in spreadsheet using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I want to get a string value to compare it later on with an if condition from only one column in a spreadsheet using Google apps script.
I searched the internet and I found this link - sorry if this sounds stupid, but I am new to Google apps scripts - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getValues();
```

I guess that must be helpful, the only problem is that the column I want to get the values from is dynamic so how do I set the range of this column?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you use simply :

`var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()`

You will get a 2 Dimension array of all the data in the sheet indexed by rows and columns.

So to get the value in column A, row1 you use `values[0][0]` , `values[1][0]` for columnA, row 2, `values[0][2]` for column C row1, etc...

If you need to iterate in a for loop (in a single column) :

```
for (n = 0; n < values.length; ++n) {
    var cell = values[n][x] ; // x is the index of the column starting from 0
}
```

If you need to iterate in a for loop (in a single row) :

```
for (n = 0; n < values[0].length; ++n) {
    var cell = values[x][n] ; // x is the index of the row starting from 0
}
```

Comment: Is this really an efficient way of doing it, though? It seems so excessive to retrieve the whole data range and then one only needs one column.

Comment: It takes the same time to get all data or just a column data, so it really doesn't make any difference:-) you can easily check that in the execution transcript where all execution times are logged by service call.

Comment: This really helps me understand 2D arrays. Thanks

Comment: There is huge difference in performance. getRange("A:A") is faster.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the script I use to get the values in a dynamic column:

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var Avals = SS.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var numberOfValues = Avals.filter(String).length;
var RangeVals = SS.getRange(1,1,numberOfValues).getValues();
```

I've never had to change which starting row based based on a dynamic changing starting point though.  Would be interested in seeing how that would be done.

Here is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562592/google-script-get-last-row-of-specific-column).
Another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108046/google-script-reducing-execution-time-below-exec-time-limit).

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you want all rows/cells in column `A` using [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation):

```
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:A").getValues();
```

Answer (score 9):

much easier way to loop through the rows and get a column value.. hope that helps

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

values.forEach( function(row) {
  row[4] // column index as 4
});
```

Answer (score 4):

All of the mentioned functions below in this answer will output a 1 dimensional array, which I feel will be slightly more convenient to operate with.

##### Solution 1:

Just another way of obtaining a column or a row:

```
function getColumn(activeSheet, columnIndex) {
  return activeSheet.getRange(1, columnIndex)
    .getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS)
    .getValues()
    .flat();
}

function getRow(activeSheet, rowIndex) {
  return activeSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1)
    .getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS)
    .getValues()[0];
}
```

**Note:** This will only fetch data which are in the adjacent cells in the given direction.

Example: 1, 2, 3, blank, 4, blank, 5  ----- 4 and 5 will be skipped. Also, see [`getDataRegion(dimension)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdataregiondimension).This is an ideal solution if you have no empty cells within the data region.

##### Solution 2:

Extending @itazzad's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66594718/11200630),

```
// JS object containing indices as keys and capital letters as value.
const INDEX_ALPHABET = Array.from(new Array(26))
  .reduce((accumulatedObj, _, index) =>
    (accumulatedObj[index + 1] = String.fromCharCode(index + 65), accumulatedObj), {});

// uses a1 notation
function getColumn(activeSheet, columnIndex) {
  var columnA1Notation = INDEX_ALPHABET[columnIndex]
  return activeSheet.getRange(columnA1Notation + ':' + columnA1Notation)
    .getValues()
    .flat();
}

// uses a1 notation
function getRow(activeSheet, rowIndex) {
  return activeSheet.getRange(rowIndex + ':' + rowIndex) 
    .getValues()[0];
}
```

See [`getRange(a1Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation). I was not sure of what R1C1 notation and A1 notation meant, but [this article](https://www.automateexcel.com/basics/cell-references/#:%7E:text=cell%20references%20work.-,A1%20vs.%20R1C1%20References,-Excel%20worksheets%20contain) helped a bit.

#### Solution 3:

If you believe [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) might be a expensive call and increases in time execution as the `Range` increases in size, then check this out. Basically it gets the last row or column and uses it to reduce the `Range` without omitting any relevant data.

```
function getRow(activeSheet, rowIndex) {
  var lastColumn = activeSheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn()
  return activeSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, lastColumn)
    .getValues()[0]
}

function getColumn(activeSheet, columnIndex) {
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow()
  return activeSheet.getRange(1, columnIndex, lastRow, 1)
    .getValues()
    .flat()
}
```

**Note:** If you want to get a slice of a row or column, check out [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the best answer so far. Suppose you want the values of Column "D1:D"

```
var numrows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getNumRows();
var columnValues = sheet.getRange(1,4,numrows,1).getValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to use Appscript to extract data from each column of Excel row by row.

```js
function readRowAndColumnsOneByOne() {
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
    var x = 0;
    for (n = 0; n < values.length; ++n) {
        for (j = 0; j < values[n].length - 1; ++j) {
            var cell = values[x][j]; // x is the index of the row starting from 0
            console.log("Number of rows " + n + " Col " + j + "- " + cell);
        }
        x++
    }
}
```