# How to pass a range into a custom function in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I am trying to compare two google sheets (for duplicate values) over a predefined range..

I am aware that google lets you compare sheets via tools, but i need a more customized comparison hence the function.

I want to create a function which takes in a range... something like:

```
    function myFunction(range) {
    var firstColumn = range.getColumn();
    // loop over the range
    }
```

The problem is that when I try doing this, the parameter seems like it is only passing the values to the function. Thus, I cannot use any of the Range methods such as getColumn(). When I attempt to do so, it gives the following error:

```
    error: TypeError: Cannot find function getColumn in object 1,2,3.
```

How can I send an actual range rather than just the values to one of my custom functions?

Note- Range in my case is the entire sheet (both of them that need to be compared).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions arguments are calculated before being passed to the code of the custom function so `range` will be a single value or an array of values.

You could pass a reference to a range as a string, i.e. `=myFunction("Sheet!A:Z")`, then use something like the following:

```
function myFunction(reference) {
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(reference);
   var firstColumn = range.getColumn();
   // do something
}
```

Note: getRangeByName work both with named ranges and references os it could be a better choice than getRange.

Answer (score 0):

Google Script treats ranges as Arrays. So, you could better work with entered range as you work with an array. Here's good technique how to loop through an array:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991272/5372400

Answer (score 0):

In your cell, you would do

```
=myFunction("A1")
```

Then in your code

```
function myFunction(ref)
{
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(ref);
    // do something with range
}
```

getRangeByName is no longer used.

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation