# Tranposing a table google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheet / google script / javascript, .
how can I convert my table

from

```
05/05/2017  Peter   Apple
05/05/2017  John    Banana
05/05/2017  Jake    Apple
05/06/2017  John    Apple
05/06/2017  Jake    Banana
05/06/2017  Peter   Banana
```

to

```
      05/05/2017    05/06/2017
Peter   Apple        Banana
John    Banana       Apple
Jake    Apple        Banana
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method of doing that I think, image attached:

[quick google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9OZZ.png)

Comment: You answered the question, but I think this is not exactly what the OP wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are asking is not transposing cells. You need keep track of:

1. Unique list of Dates
2. Unique list of Names
3. Find all the intersections.

---

You also need to solve this Q:

- What if data have more then 1 matches for pair: date-name i.e. `Peter` in `05/05/2017` has `Apple` and `Banana`

Try solving the problem by parts and then come up with some code and improve it.

I suggest these info as starting point:

[get value in one column in spreadsheet using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991030/get-value-in-one-column-in-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script)

[Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
1: Paste the table in B1 across D6.

2: In A1 enter this formula -> =ArrayFormula(C1:C&B1:B)

3. In F1, enter this -> =TRANSPOSE(unique({B:B}))

4. IN E2, enter this -> =UNIQUE(C:C)

5. In F2, enter this -> =ArrayFormula(iferror(VLOOKUP($E2:$E&F1,$A1:$D,4,0),""))
```

You can grad the formula in F2 across next columns to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not full-explained, so the answer is based on this assumption:
for each distinct date and for each distinct name the source range contans exactly one data row. Thus we will not take care of possible data aggregation.

The image below is useful to explain the solution.

[image]

Row headers array in E4:E6 is filled by the formula `=UNIQUE($B$1:$B$6)`, because we should avoid duplicates. The formula is for the cell E4.
Column headers array with dates are calculated by a similar formula with additional transposition `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE($A$1:$A$6))` in the cell F3.

At last, data cells F4:G6 have the same logics and their formula can be expanded by copying from the cell F4. The result should be found in column C using 2 keys for A and B columns. There is no "VLOOKUP-like" function to do that directly, so we use filtering before VLOOKUP.

More information about these functions can be found here: [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318), [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197).