# Google Script - get last row of specific column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to find the last row (with data) of specific column. Let's say column A last data item in row 100 and column B has last data item in row 50.

.getLastRow(); will always return 100 to me.

I need a simple way to get 50 instead (which is the row number of last non empty row in column B).

I can't use loops. It's very important as there are thousands of rows, it will simply take too much time.

I've googled a lot, but all answers involve looping.