# Google Sheets: How to find the last row of each column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet filled with data in each column and they all have different length in rows. Since I will need to audit the data everyday at 4pm, but other people will continue to add data in each column at the same time, so I am trying to find the last cell of every column and highlight that cell with value into red so I know its a cutoff.

But i am wondering how to find the last cell with value of every column and highlight it into red with Google Apps Script?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer with this thread: [Google Script - get last row of specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562592/google-script-get-last-row-of-specific-column).

> You can also use the following code:
>
> ```
> function findTheLastRow(){
>   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
>   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
>
>   var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
>   var filtered_r = range.filter(String).length;
>
>   ui.alert("Column B's last cell is number: " + filtered_r + " and its value is: " + range[filtered_r - 1][0]);
> }
> ```
>
> This script counts the amount of cells that have a value in a column,
>   so the cells above the last cell needs to have a value in order to get
>   the right result.

You may also check this link for additional reference:

- [How to find the last cell value at the end of a specific row](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/OGWBx-gHa4c)

Answer (score -1):

Press CTR + Right side arrow - for last cell of row
Press CRT + Down side arrow - for go to the last column

Comment: this isn't an apps script answer, which was the question. @bluery is this not the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column, plus looping through all the columns?