# How to get the next empty row in a specific column google spreadsheet using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to update the next rows in a spreadsheet with some data and for that, I need to find the last row. However, I need to get the last value in column A and not other columns. The function below works well and gets me the last row in column A that has value but returns that one and I need the row below the one with the value.

```js
function getLastDataRow(sheet) {
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow);

  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
   }              
}
```

I am new to both JavaScript (python user) as well as Google Apps Script so I could really use some help with this as I have been trying all evening to get the first row in column A that is empty after the one with the value. For example if A20 has the last value, I want to return 21 and not 20.

Comment: I use [getColumnHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55425107/7215091)

Comment: How about this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44562592

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks but I already have a way of finding the first non-empty cell searching from bottom. I just don't know how to get the next row, the one that is empty. It is that specific part I am interested in. You are giving me a valid solution that could be used but not really an answer I am asking for. Still, thank you.

Comment: The solution I used was quite simple but very ugly, it is instead of var target = "A" + getLastDataRow ( sheet ); I used var target = "A" + (getLastDataRow ( sheet )+1);

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I was using the following code to get a range and update the cells with new content:

```
if (projdoc.match(regExp)) { 
projdocnum = regExp.exec(projdoc)[1]; 
var target = "A" + (getLastDataRow ( sheet )+1); 
var regExp2 = new RegExp("[A-Za-z]+([0-9]+)","g"); 
var targetnum = regExp2.exec(target)[1]; var rangesheet = sheet.getRange(target+":D"+targetnum);
rangesheet.setValues([[ID, projectname, projdoc, projdocnum]]);
}
```

The only thing I changed was in earlier versions I had :

```
var target = "A" + (getLastDataRow ( sheet )); and I just added +1 to it to get the next row.
```