# How can I use dynamic variable numbers in a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I created a little tool that allows us to use a G sheet as the source for a G doc template. Essentially, it takes the values from the G sheet and replaces the placesholders in the template with the respective values.

Here I am declaring the variables:

```
  var MB_1 =  ws.getRange("C1").getValue();
```

And here I am replacing the document's body text with the respective values:

```
  var docBody = DocumentApp.openById(createdFileId).getBody();
  docBody
  .replaceText("{mbd_1}", MB_1)
```

The thing is that I have 300 variables and I want to avoid having something like this:

```
var docBody = DocumentApp.openById(createdFileId).getBody();
  docBody
  .replaceText("{mbd_1}", MB_1) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_2}", MB_2) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_3}", MB_3) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_4}", MB_4) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_5}", MB_5) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_6}", MB_6) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_7}", MB_7) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_8}", MB_8) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_9}", MB_9) 
  .replaceText("{mbd_10}", MB_10)
```

So, long story short: How can I loop that replaceText part for 300 variables? I've seen solutions with "this." but I couldn't figure how to use it in this context.

Your support is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are they in a same column? Show how you declare other MB variables.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991272/1101930. When iterating over the array you can limit the code for each cell per column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a variable for each single value, and reading one value at a time, as it's being done in

```
var MB_1 =  ws.getRange("C1").getValue();
```

read all the values at once

```
var MB = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
```

*Note: To get the values as they are formatted in Google Sheets, instead of `getValues` use `getDisplayValues()`.*

then use Array indexes as follows

```
docBody
  .replaceText("{mbd_1}", MB[0][2])
```

Depending on your spreadsheet structure, you could take it further, i.e. using a loop (assuming that all the values are in Column C), like the following:

```
MB.forEach((row,i) => docBody.replaceText(`{mbd_${i + 1}}`, MB[i][2]))
```

References

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Hola Rubén 
Thank you for your swift answer. I have two question regarding your solution:

a) Depending on the value type I have to format it differently. For currency values I use "var MB_28 =  formatStringCurrency(ws.getRange("C28").getValue());" for example. Date and percentage are other types. How can I individually format them? I don't see a way to identify the different formats without assigning the formatting functions to the respective variables individually.

b) I would need to have that mbd_1 variable dynamic as well to match the MB variable that it is replace with. 

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the first question, a) apply the required formats in Google Sheets, then instead of getValues use getDisplayValues. b) to handle strings as `mbd_1` dynamically I already suggested to use <code>`{mbd_${i + i}}`</code> P.S. there was  a misplaced `, fixed and added a reference.

Comment: The backticks are not shown correctly in my previous comment, the dynamic mbd_1 should be shown as  \`{mbd_${i + i}}\`

Comment: @TheMaster Because the OP's placeholders are 1 based instead of 0 based

Comment: @TheMaster You are right (sorry... I should use my glasses)

Comment: Splendid, that this the job! Thanks a lot!